# Fabric.js New Class from existing Shape fromObject Error

Tags: javascript, subclass, fabricjs

In my continuing saga of trying to make a custom class in Fabric.js that can be saved and loaded. I'm trying to extend the Line and Circle class and add some custom attributes... But I'm running to a problem when attempting to load the data. It saves ok, my simple 'name' attribute is there, but when attempting to load, I get stuck in the "enlivenObjects" function, namely where the klass gets that object type from the fabric.util.getKlass function. I get nothing back for my objects ("undefined").
In the attached example, if you click "SAVE" the data for the canvas is put into a DIV, you can then "Clear" the canvas and try to "LOAD" the data. The error occurs when trying to load. 
So, in a JS Console window, I can run "fabric.util.getKlass('Line')" and that works, I get an object back, but when I do the same with my 'namedCircle' or 'namedLine' I get undefined... 
Any thoughts? Is this approach not going to work for me?

```js
var canvas;
            
    window.onload = function() {
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        /**
         * Attempt to make a custom Line, inherited from the fabric.Line
         * currently has a custom attribute of 'name'
         * 
         */
        fabric.namedLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
            type: 'namedLine',
            initialize: function(points, options) {
                options || (options = { });
                this.callSuper('initialize', points, options);
                this.set('name', options.name || '');
            },
            toObject: function() {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                name: this.get('name')
                });
            },
            fromObject: function(object, callback) {
                return fabric.Object._fromObject('namedLine', options, callback);
            },
            _render: function(ctx) {
                this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
            }
        });

        /**
         * Attempt at custom Circle, inherited from fabric.Circle with
         * a 'name' attribute.
         * 
         */
        fabric.namedCircle = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Circle, {
            type: 'namedCircle',
            initialize: function(options) {
                options || (options = { });
                this.callSuper('initialize', options);
                this.set('name', options.name || '');
            },
            toObject: function() {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                name: this.get('name')
                });
            },
            fromObject: function(object, callback) {
                return fabric.Object._fromObject('namedCircle', object, callback);
            },
            _render: function(ctx) {
                this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
            }
        });
        
        fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

        // First Create our line.
        var line = makeLine([ 250, 125, 250, 175 ], "myLine");
        canvas.add(line);
        
        // Now we create our circles, linking to our line.
        canvas.add(
            // first circle is at top of line, line1 is null, line2 is the line.
            makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), "head", null, line),

            // second circle is at the bottom, line 1 is the line, nothing for line 2.
            makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), "tail", line),
        );

        canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
            var p = e.target;
            // set bottom of the line to the shapes left and top position.
            p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
            // set the top to the line to the circle position.
            p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        // Add our button events.
        document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", saveData);
        document.getElementById("btnLoad").addEventListener("click", loadData);
        document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", clearData);

    };

    // our circle has up to 2 links.
    function makeCircle(left, top, name, line1, line2) {
        var c = new fabric.namedCircle({
            left: left,
            top: top,
            strokeWidth: 5,
            radius: 12,
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#666',
            name: name
        });
        c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

        c.line1 = line1;
        c.line2 = line2;

        return c;
    }

    function makeLine(coords, name) {
        return new fabric.namedLine(coords, {
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            selectable: false,
            name: name
        });
    }

    function saveData() {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    };

    function loadData() {
        var data = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML;
        console.log(data);
        canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(data);
        canvas.renderAll();
    };

    function clearData() {
        canvas.clear();
    }
```

```css
#out {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas style="border: 2px solid; " height="500" width="600" id="c"></canvas>
<p>
  <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
  <button id="btnClear">Clear</button>
  <button id="btnLoad">Load</button>
</p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, sometimes you just need to step away from things and think about it.
I took a closer look at the getKlass function, and it Capitalizes the first character of the class name... So the fix is to change the classes from "namedLine" and "namedCircle" to "NamedLine" and "NamedCircle".
The other thing I had to do was move the return function outside of the class.

```js
    var canvas;
            
    /**
     * Attempt to make a custom Line, inherited from the fabric.Line
     * currently has a custom attribute of 'name'
     * 
     */
        fabric.NamedLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
        type: 'NamedLine',
        initialize: function(points, options) {
            options || (options = { });
            this.callSuper('initialize', points, options);
            this.set('name', options.name || '');
        },
        toObject: function() {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            name: this.get('name')
            });
        },
        _render: function(ctx) {
            this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        }
    });
    fabric.NamedLine.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
        callback && callback(new fabric.NamedLine([object.x1, object.y1, object.x2, object.y2], object));
    };


    /**
     * Attempt at custom Circle, inherited from fabric.Circle with
     * a 'name' attribute.
     * 
     */
    fabric.NamedCircle = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Circle, {
        type: 'NamedCircle',
        initialize: function(options) {
            options || (options = { });
            this.callSuper('initialize', options);
            this.set('name', options.name || '');
        },
        toObject: function() {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            name: this.get('name')
            });
        },
        _render: function(ctx) {
            this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        }
    });

    fabric.NamedCircle.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
        return fabric.Object._fromObject('NamedCircle', object, callback);
    };

    fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';




    window.onload = function() {
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        
        // First Create our line.
        var line = makeLine([ 250, 125, 250, 175 ], "myLine");
        canvas.add(line);
        
        // Now we create our circles, linking to our line.
        canvas.add(
            // first circle is at top of line, line1 is null, line2 is the line.
            makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), "head", null, line),

            // second circle is at the bottom, line 1 is the line, nothing for line 2.
            makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), "tail", line),
        );

        canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
            var p = e.target;
            // set bottom of the line to the shapes left and top position.
            p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
            // set the top to the line to the circle position.
            p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        // Add our button events.
        document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", saveData);
        document.getElementById("btnLoad").addEventListener("click", loadData);
        document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", clearData);

    };

    // our circle has up to 2 links.
    function makeCircle(left, top, name, line1, line2) {
        var c = new fabric.NamedCircle({
            left: left,
            top: top,
            strokeWidth: 5,
            radius: 12,
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#666',
            name: name
        });
        c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

        c.line1 = line1;
        c.line2 = line2;

        return c;
    }

    function makeLine(coords, name) {
        return new fabric.NamedLine(coords, {
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            selectable: false,
            name: name
        });
    }

    function saveData() {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    };

    function loadData() {
        var data = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML;
        console.log(data);
        canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(data);
        canvas.renderAll();
    };

    function clearData() {
        canvas.clear();
    }
```

```css
#out {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas style="border: 2px solid; " height="500" width="600" id="c"></canvas>
<p>
  <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
  <button id="btnClear">Clear</button>
  <button id="btnLoad">Load</button>
</p>
<div id="out"></div>
```